# Adding a Equinox OSGI hook throwing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox

I'm trying to add a BundleWatcher hook in my OSGi container so that I can monitor bundles as they are loaded. I have made the following changes in config.ini,

1. Added a reference to my jar in the osgi.bundles property like so,
   osgi.bundles = , reference\:file\:../lib/my.jar@2:start
2. Set the property osgi.framework.extensions = mybundle
3. Add MyBundleWatcher as a hook in osgi.hook.configurators.include

Also my jar file is in the same directory as the OSGi bundle.

When I run my app I get a ClassNotFoundException for my BundleWatcher.

I can confirm however that my bundle (which contains the BundleWatcher) is indeed started as the start method of the Activator in my bundle is called.

What am I doing wrong?

As a background here are a couple of articles I followed,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Adaptor_Hooks

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/01/23/how-to-track-lifecycle-changes-of-osgi-bundles/

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use the Equinox specific `BundleWatcher` — which requires special access to Equinox internals and configuration — versus the OSGi standard `BundleTracker`, which can be implemented by any bundle and will work on any framework implementation?

Comment: I guess in my case I am ok with using something equinox specific. My goal is to have my plugin be launched first so that I can monitor the loading of the rest of the plugins. BundleTracker does not seem to be able to do it BundleWatcher can.

Comment: That's not true. BundleTracker is notified about the state of all the bundles it is interested, both the ones that start before it and the ones that start after it. There are **no** advantages to using the Equinox-specific BundleWatcher.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be going out of your way to make it complicated. You make it an extension (like a device driver) and use proprietary code. There might be some rationale if you wanted to see ALL bundles installed, but you won't see the install events for already installed bundles anyway when you do a restart. So if you can live with just seeing all the bundles as they come alive then by far simplest solution to track what bundles get installed is:

```
package tracker;
public class Watch implements BundleActivator {
  BundleTracker<Bundle> tracker;

  public void start(BundleContext context) {
    tracker = new BundleTracker<Bundle>( context, -1, null ) {
       public Bundle addingBundle( Bundle b, BundleEvent e) {
          System.out.println("Tracking bundle " + b.getSymbolicName());
          return b;
       }
    };
    tracker.open();
  }

  public void stop(BundleContext context) {}
}
```

Manifest:

```
Bundle-Activator: tracker.Watch
```

Comment: I really do want to be able to monitor the loading of each and every bundle.

Comment: Then you need to control the OSGi launcher. Install a BundleListener or BundleTracker before the framework starts. As Peter says, you still won't get the install events for bundles that were installed last time the framework ran. Perhaps if you gave your motivation for wanting this -- rather than merely insisting that you want it -- then a good solution can be found.

Comment: You must have an awfully important reason to go through this complexity. Can you explain why you need to see things as they happen (which is often a red herring anyway)?